# Trimming header's captions in DevExpress' GridView(6.3v)

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am having the problem with setting character elipsis triming, both with word wrapping option in GridView component.

I have changed the height of the header to about 40 px, then set: HeaderPanel.TextOptions.
Trimming to: EllipsisCharacter. 
I saw then that single line is trimmed with ellipsis added - successfully.

Next step was to add word wrapping to Wrap. Then ellipsis is never added and
I can see only words of the header caption which fits in the width of the column.

How Can I correctly wrap the header with ellipsis being added when the caption doesn't fit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap and elipsis are rivals. You can use either one or the other.

Comment: What about this link: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/paulk/archive/2009/12/21/wrapping-column-headers-in-the-winforms-gridcontrol.aspx There you can see in the picture wrapped header with ellipsis added.